# Thunderbird: export email account settings

Tags: backup, thunderbird, export

I'd like to create a new profile for Thunderbird using the same mail accounts I already configured in my old profile. As it is quite a number of accounts, it would be great to have a way to export/import them instead of writing down the settings just to fill in again in the new profile.

Using web search and search here I mainly found following suggestions that do not match what I need:

1. *Copy the whole profile*: Not possible for me as I don't want to copy other settings, the downloaded mail data etc. and the old profile broke when running out of space in the home folder anyway.
2. *Use mozBackup*: There seem to be several programs by that name (forks?). In any case, it's Windows-only and hence no option (I am mostly on Linux and prefer platform-independent solutions anyway)
3. Use [accountex](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/accountex/): Seems to do what I want, but it is not compatible with current Thunderbird version (supports only up to version 3.1)
4. Posts with various tips from > 4 years ago: Top results in the web search with the G. But they do not work in current versions of Thunderbird either.

Did I overlook anything? After all, it doesn't sound like I was looking for something nobody ever looked for.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could copy the relevant `prefs.js` items manually.

- `mail.account.*`
- `mail.accountmanager.*`
- `mail.identity.*`
- `mail.server.*`
- `mail.smtpserver.*`
- `mail.smtpservers`

For example:

```
egrep 'user_pref\("mail\.(account(manager)?|identity|(smtp)?servers?)[."]' \
    < old-profile/prefs.js >> new-profile/prefs.js
```

The file is located in your Thunderbird [profile directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird), uses the same format on all platforms, and even on all Thunderbird versions (hasn't changed much from Netscape Navigator days, I believe).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really did not suspect the file to be that stable, nor being anything this easy to migrate.

Comment: @grawity, your understanding of the meaning of the word 'manually' and mine differ by galaxies! Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: It's possible this approach has a fault: I can't see any of my newsgroup accounts in my account settings under "Preferences > Accounts". The newsgroup accounts are there in the Folder view pane, but I can't get to the Account settings for them! I guess I need to copy newsgroup settings as well...

Comment: Can't work out how to transfer newsgroup settings so they appear in accounts manager. @grawity could you have a look or do you know how?